# Why is chrome.action.onClicked.addListener not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Why does clicking the action icon in chrome not return a result?

I'm developing in chrome and want to `console.log` when the action icon is clicked. Looking at the console, the first script in my `background.js` file works (tracking the current URL), however, nothing is returned when the icon is clicked. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Chrome Extension with React & Webpack",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": { "service_worker": "background.bundle.js" },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Click to show an alert"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.bundle.js"],
      "css": ["content.styles.css"]
    }
  ],
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["popup.html", "content.styles.css", "icon-128.png", "icon-34.png"],
      "matches": [],
       "extension_ids": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**Background.js**

```
//This works
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
  console.log("TAB UPDATED")
  getTab().then(url => {
      console.log(url);
  })
})

async function getTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tabs[0].url;
}

//Nothing is console logged
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => { console.log('test')});
```

Comment: I deleted my earlier answer since it doesn't solve the question, but I have a concern: after adding version to manifest and the other referenced files, this original example works as intended. I recommend updating the manifest to exactly what you have, and the exact script that produces the issue, to solicit more answers to help resolve this.